# facebook sdk about opengraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a contact ios beginners facebook sdk opengraph encounter some problems, I use this youtube website to learn opengraph see some php programming language

Will opengraph whether the need to develop the background and servers to cooperate with each other?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x6T7-WFSBg

I hope to give me some advice and help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best to start learning Facebook iOS SDK is from [Facebook developer site](http://developers.facebook.com). As you will be familiar with the naming conventions used it won't be difficult to get through.

[Download](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/) the SDK from the developer site, it includes most of the sample codes.

For getting started to login/logout you can go through [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, and those I have implemented the sample, and most do not understand only open graph